# MVC3 Remote Validation of a field within a List

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, list, remote-validation

For some reason, whenever I try to remotely validate a primitive property inside an array within my model, the value of the property is not passed as a parameter.

For example, when my remote validation method (UniqueItemNo) is called, the string parameter "id" is always null. If I were to perform validation on CartNumber instead of ItemNumber, the parameter is passed correctly.

### Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        CartModel cart = new CartModel();
        cart.Items.Add(new ItemModel() { ItemNumber = "12345" });
        return View(cart);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UniqueItemNo(string id)
    {
        /** Do Work **/
        return null;
    }
}
```

### Models

```
public class ItemModel
{
    [Remote("UniqueItemNo", "Home", HttpMethod="POST")]
    public string ItemNumber { get; set; }
}

public class CartModel
{
    public CartModel()
    {
        Items = new List<ItemModel>();
    }

    public List<ItemModel> Items { get; set; }
    public string CartNumber { get; set; }
}
```

### View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
@using(Html.BeginForm()) {
    <p>
        @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Items[i].ItemNumber);
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Items[i].ItemNumber);                                    
        }
    </p>
}
```

Answer (score 7):

just solved the same problem. so for my type of people who are going to have this problem in future, here is the solution

here is the root cause.

when you do `@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.m.Items[i].ItemNumber)`
it outputs something like this

```
<input type=text value='value' name='items[index].ItemNumber' ...
```

and then it adds the other validations like data-* attributes for validation. e.g. remote validation url data-remot-url and etc

now when form got validated it requested the remote url with data like key=xxx[1].propertyname

and this is not assignable to a single variable in remote action method that will receive this property.

if you will change the action arguments to something like this, then it will work

```
 public JsonResult UniqueItemNo(list<string> propertyname)
```

and even then you are not guranteed as it requires to have the parameters index start from 0 and without any gap. so xxx[1].ItemNumber will never get maped.

the only remaining solution is to get the property name from querystring and map it to your required variable. like this

```
    if(Request.QueryString.AllKeys.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ToLower().Contains("propertyname"))!=null)
    {
                     propertyname = Request.QueryString[Request.QueryString.AllKeys.First(p => p.ToLower().Contains("propertyname"))];
}
```

it will search and map the required variables.

hope this will help

Comment: thanks, it helps me a lot! In fact, it is strange why ASP MVC create request to remote validation endpoint using parameters named `ItemViewModelsCollection[i].ItemProperty` Instead of `ItemProperty`. Usually such a actions use different contact, which is simplified especially for single property validation.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you found an answer already, but in case you didn't, try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UniqueItemNo()
{
    var itemNumber = Request.Form[Request.Form.AllKeys.First(p => p.Contains("ItemNumber"))];

    /** Do Work **/
    return Json(true);
}
```

Note that @Mamoon ur Rasheed answer was almost correct, but since you're using POST your parameters will be inside the Form property, not QueryString.

Let me know if you still have any issues regarding this.

Btw, you should use a try/catch. I didn't wrote it just to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the parameter to match the model. Like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UniqueItemNo(ItemModel itemModel)
    {
        // look at itemModel.ItemNumber...
        /** Do Work **/
        return null;
    }
```

You can still start the name of the `ActionMethod` parameter with lowercase (`itemNumber` instead of `ItemNumber`) as per the normal coding conventions.

**EDIT:** Have you tried coding the `View` like this?

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
        @foreach (var item in Items)
        {
           @using(Html.BeginForm()) {
              <p>
                 @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.CartNumber)
                 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.ItemNumber);
                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => item.ItemNumber);                                    
              </p>
           }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I just tried it, and the parameter is still null. Any other ideas?

Comment: Your view looks odd to me. Try changing it to be like the one above.

Comment: I changed the view to what you have above but, unfortunately, it still doesn't work.

Comment: To be honest, when I've done this (I just checked my shopping cart code that works), I've done a new form for each line, a bit like the edit I've just made above. And make you sure include the cart number as a hidden value if you need it too.

Comment: I'm out of ideas, which is why I came to stackoverflow. I have no clue as to why this code doesn't work as intended...

Comment: Did you try my new code where you create a new form for each element? If that doesn't work then I reckon I'm stumped too :-(

Comment: Yeah, I tried it but no luck :(.

I guess I'll have to do server-side validation instead...

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the entry to the `ActionMethod` and then looking at `Request.Form.AllKeys` in the immediate window?

Comment: Just tried it right now, there is one key with the value "item.ItemNumber"

Comment: In that case, change the object being passed to the `ActionMethod` as shown above. I should have spotted that earlier, I must be getting feeble in my old age... lol!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you don't have support for this.

In client side the remote validation is handled by jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js which says

```
...
$.each(splitAndTrim(options.params.additionalfields || options.element.name), function (i, fieldName) {
    var paramName = appendModelPrefix(fieldName, prefix);
    value.data[paramName] = function () {
        return $(options.form).find(":input[name='" + escapeAttributeValue(paramName) + "']").val();
    };
});
...
```

so you should notice that for each additional field it constructs just one parameter in query string (or in form if you do post). because of that you server side remote attribute should look like

```
[Remote("UniqueItemNo", AdditionalFields = "ItemNumber[0],ItemNumber[1],...")]
```

fact that you don't know at design time.

you could use a js hack and keep a hidden field named ItemNumber and with value a concatenated list of ids. on server side you should change the type of ItemNumber array into string and split the values.

I hope this helps although it's a long time since you asked.